# C# Won't insert into database while accessing values on a usercontrol

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a user control called Payslip, it has textboxes, combobox and labels. It is accessed by a form called NewPayroll. NewPayroll has a save button which is supposed to save the information on the Payslip, to the database.

However it won't insert and no exception is raised.

Code for save button:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scon.Open();

    if (materialTabControl1.TabCount > 0)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save all?", "Save as...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into [SalaryInfo] (SlipId, Fname, Lname, DeptCode, NetPay, GrossPay, Date, Year) VALUES (@id, @fname, @lname, @deptcode, @netpay, @gpay, @date, @year)", scon);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", payslip.txtSlipCode.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", payslip.lblFirstName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", payslip.lblSurname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deptcode", payslip.lblDeptnum.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@netpay", payslip.lblNetPay.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gpay", payslip.txtSalary.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", payslip.lblDate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", DateTime.Today.Year.ToString());

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                lblMessage.Text = "Saving...";
                pnlSnackBar.Visible = true;
                SnackBarTimer();

                scon.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Saving! \n \n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
When I click save a second time, an exception occurs that says:
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tmp_ms_x_1B2F5BA524452F43'.
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SalaryInfo'. The duplicate key value is '(XXFJE)'.
The statement has been terminated.

**NOTE: XXFJE is a randomly generated code for payslip.**

Comment: What type of database - LocalDB or other variant?  How are you verifying that the data is not inserted?  Via your app, or via a query against the DB?

Comment: also, just to be safe, ensure that the payslip.lblDeptnum.Text is referring to a valid Deptnum in the Dept table.  Assuming the deptcode is a FK.

Comment: @Brendan Green, The database is a SQL LocalDB. No verification has been added, however when I check the table after clicking save, no information has been added.

Comment: What's `scon`? How do you “check the table”?

Comment: @Dour High Arch, scon is the SqlConnection string. I haven't input any code to check if it already exists.

Comment: What is **the value of** `scon`? What does your connection string contain? You said “when I check the table after clicking save, no information has been added”. How do you “check the table”? What makes you think “no information has been added”? According to your error message, the `SlipID` was indeed inserted.

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns the number of records that were inserted.  If it's greater than zero, and you cannot see the records, you are looking in the wrong database.

Comment: @Dour High Arch, `scon = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.PayrollDatabaseConnectionString);` the connection string is referenced from the App.Config file.

Comment: @LarsTech wrong database? There's only one database connected to the application.

Comment: @JeremyJames I don't know what your connection string looks like.  Is it using the Data Directory?

Comment: I agree with other comments that you are looking at the wrong database which is easy to do. Also put the line "scon.Open();" as the first line after the try.  Open as late as possible is a rule and you will never close if any of the next 2 if conditions are false. Also waiting for a user to respond should never be after an Open.

Comment: @LarsTech `Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PayrollDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30`

Comment: Look at the property window for the local database.  I'm guessing you have  "Copy To Output" set to "Copy Always".  If so, you are looking at a copy of the database.

Comment: @LarsTech I can't view the properties since it wasn't added to the form as a control. However the thing that puzzles me the most is in the exception I get after trying to add a second time right after I try to add the first time. `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tmp_ms_x_1B2F5BA524452F43'`...SalaryInfo has a relationship with another table so it should have said, `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SalaryInfo_EmployeeInfo'`, instead.

Comment: If the data source is in the solution tree, just highlight it and then look at the properties window.

Comment: @LarsTech ok, yes it's set to "Copy always"...should I change it to "Copy if newer"?

Comment: That's your preference.  I was never a fan of the DataDirectory feature, and it's tripped up many, many programmers.  I actually never put the data source into my solution.  I just put the database in a location and use a static database string to connect to it in all my code.

Comment: @LarsTech it's still not being inserted...it looks to me like the information from the usercontrol isn't being called, in the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()...` section.

Comment: Well. what is the returned value of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`?  If it's one, it inserted.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm not getting a returned value

Comment: What does that mean?  Is it returning a value of zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after many hours of trying to find a solution, I finally did.
The database .mdf file in the solution tree was set to "Copy always", which created a separate database file in `bin/Debug` when the program is run. I changed it to "Do not copy" and changed the connection string in App.Config to the location of the database file I originally was using.

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you for the help, it was your suggestion about there being a wrong database that get me trying different things.

Answer (score -1):

In your database with table SalaryInfo have a primary key and then when you insert your table, this primary key duplication value. Because, value primary key is only!!!
You can alter table with primary key indentity. and when you insert you can 
ignore it.

Example: Field SlipId is Primary key
When insert you can :

```
try{

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into [SalaryInfo] (Fname, Lname, DeptCode, NetPay, GrossPay, Date, Year) VALUES (@fname, @lname, @deptcode, @netpay, @gpay, @date, @year)", scon);
    // code here.....

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Error Saving! \n \n" + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: This does not address the original question in any way.

Comment: @Bendan Green.  Agreed.